# create multiple new data frames in a loop by subsetting another and adding a suffix

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of dataframes that I would like to use to create new dataframes with by subsetting a fixed list of columns and adding a suffix to. Thus far I make a list of all my dataframes:

```
buckets_list = ['one_season_bucket_year1',
'two_season_bucket_year1',
'two_season_bucket_year2',
'three_season_bucket_year1',
'three_season_bucket_year2',
'three_season_bucket_year3',
'four_season_bucket_year1',
'four_season_bucket_year2',
'four_season_bucket_year3',
'five_season_bucket_year1',
'five_season_bucket_year2',
'five_season_bucket_year3',
'five_season_bucket_year4',
'five_season_bucket_year5']
```

I have a list of all the columns I want to subset:

```
player_bio_list = ['games',
'height',
'position',
'minutes']
```

and I try to make a for loop to make a new dataframe:

```
for bucket in buckets_list:
    vars()[str(bucket) + "player_bio"]= pd.DataFrame(bucket[player_bio_list])
```

but I get an error saying "TypeError: string indices must be integers", what am I missing here? I have googled that error with little success since it happens a lot of reasons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buckets_list` is simply a list of strings and not of dataframes. And if you really want to keep the names of the variables and add a prefix, have `buckets_list` be a dictionary in the following format: `{dataframe_variable_name: dataframe_object`, and iterate through it by using `for key, val in buckets_list.items():`, where the `key` will be the variable name and `val` will be the dataframe object.

EDIT: for clarification and answering the OP's comment

```
buckets_list = {dataframe1_name: dataframe1,
                dataframe2_name: dataframe2,
                ...}
```

Just fill it up with all the dataframes you want...

Comment: thank you very much, would you mind showing how to make said dictionary?

Comment: buckets_list = {dataframe1_name: dataframe1,
                        dataframe2_name: dataframe2,
                        ...}